# Magento 2 Configurable product still show even all it's simple product are out of stock

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, inventory

We are experiencing a weird issue with our Magento 2 website, that the configurable product is still showing on the front-end even all it's simple products related are **out of stock.** And we have in Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->**Display Out Of stock**, set to **NO**.

Is there anything we have missed in the configuration?

Comment: Have you run indexing commands?

Comment: @PareshaU You are right, I seems I need to update product indexing even it shows status ready in admin. Efter updated the indexing, the configurable is disappeared from the front-end. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run below commands to see the result.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

**OR**

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product catalog_product_category catalog_product_attribute

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: if you found this answer helpful please accept it so its also helpful others.